# What is the best way to update a table by removing only one leading zero from numeric values in a column in SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently, I have a column with 10 digits with leading '0' on all the records and I want to remove that '0' and keep 9 digits only even if it's start with a zero. I want to later join that table with another table in that column and the other table has 9 digits on all record and some start with 0.

Comment: `substring(col, 2, 9)`, but it would be easier when you store numeric data in a numeric datatype, of course.

Comment: It is not a numeric value if it has a leading zero.

Comment: I tried the substring (col, 2, 9) and it worked fine and fast. It took 7 minutes for 186 million records.

Answer (score 1):

If only the first digit is a 0 and the column is a numeric type you can convert it to int at the time of joining:

This will remove every 0 at the beginning

```
FROM table1 inner join table2 on CAST(table1.col as int) = table2.col
```

You can also substring it:

```
FROM table1 inner join table2 on substring(table1.col, 2, 9) = table2.col
```

Those two options are to be done at the moment of joining, however, you can just alter the table to update every value in the column if you convert the column's data type to int, but it will remove every 0 from the beginning, much like the first option:

```
ALTER TABLE table1
ALTER COLUMN col int;
```

Comment: To add to what Luis has suggested, if you take the approach of using either CAST or SUBSTRING, I would do that in an Indexed view so that the join you need to thereafter does not need to perform either task during the join, potentially over an increasing number of records.

Comment: OP stated that he wants to keep 9 digits,  EVEN if the first of those 9 is a 0

Comment: Then he can substring the first column at the moment of joining.

Comment: Yes, or have the review return both the manipulated column as well as the original string value. The join could be on the indexed manipulated column.

Answer (score 0):

If the column is a varchar and has always 10 digits that start with a 0 ?

Then [RIGHT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/right-transact-sql) might be right for it.

```
declare @T1 table (id1 int identity(1,1) primary key, var_10 varchar(10));
insert into  @T1 (var_10) values ('0123456789');

declare @T2 table (id2 int identity(1,1) primary key, var_09 varchar(9));
insert into  @T2 (var_09) values ('123456789');

select * 
from @T1 t1
join @T2 t2 on t2.var_09 = right(t1.var_10, 9);
```

But if you're not too sure about it, then I would suggest to [TRY_CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql) (or TRY_CAST) them both to an INT.

```
select * 
from @T1 t1
join @T2 t2 on try_convert(int,t2.var_09) = try_convert(int,t1.var_10);
```

A TRY_CONVERT has the benifit over a CONVERT that if some of the data doesn't contain numbers that the SQL wouldn't crash on that.
But f.e. a `CONVERT(int,'123FOOBAR')` would crash the SQL.
While a `TRY_CONVERT(int,'123FOOBAR')` would just return a NULL.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it for a join then cast to int is probably more efficient

```
FROM table1 
inner join table2 
   on CAST(table1.col as int) = CAST(table2.col as int)
```